# java -xvf test.jar not working

Tags: linux, unix, jar, extract

i tried to extract the test.jar
command is executing successfully **but no output.**

```
user@host:home/test->ll
drwxr-xr-x 107 user abc  6040 Apr  4 09:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 user abc    26 Apr  4 10:06 .
-rw-r--r--   1 user abc 51241 Apr  4 10:06 test.jar
user@host:home/test->jar -xvf test.jar
user@host:home/test->ll
total 262
drwxr-xr-x 107 user abc  6040 Apr  4 09:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 user abc    26 Apr  4 10:06 .
-rw-r--r--   1 user abc 51241 Apr  4 10:06 test.jar
```

Kindly help me to resolve this

**Actual Requirement:**
Need to extract and access a resource in jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Oracle Java toutorials:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html
You should unpack it with:

```
jar xfv test.jar
```

Without '-' sign.

> x option indicates that you want to extract files from the JAR archive.
>
> f options indicates that the JAR file from which files are to be extracted is specified on the command line, rather than through stdin.
>
> v is verbose

Answer (score 0):

try to this command also `unzip test.jar` and below commands help you view some file without extract all the files.

```
unzip -q -c test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```